# Ionic 3 & Angular 4 : generate ion-select from 2 loops in view

Tags: angular, ionic3, ion-select

I'm trying to generate multiple ion-select from an array in my view.

Explain :

I've an array like this :

```
this.childrenTags = [
    [
        { 'id_tag': 1, 'label': 'test-1' }
    ],
    [
        { 'id_tag': 1, 'label': 'test-1' },
        { 'id_tag': 2, 'label': 'test-2' },
        { 'id_tag': 3, 'label': 'test-3' }
    ]
]
```

I want to generate ion-select in my view to have 2 selects for this var : 
one select displaying only **"test-1"** and a second displaying **"test-1","test-2", "test-3"**

I have a first loop doing this :

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let parentLabel of parentsTags; index as k;">
     <ion-label stacked>{{parentLabel}} - {{k}}</ion-label>
     <tags-list-component [tagsList]="childrenTags" [index]="k"></tags-list-component>
</ion-row>
```

parentTags contain a simple array like `["Test 1","Test 2"]`.

My `tags-list-component` looks like :

```
<ion-select id="children-tag-{{index}}" required cancelText="{{'buttons.cancel' | translate}}">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let tag of tagsList[index]" value="{{tag.id_tag}}-{{index}}">{{tag.label}} - {{index}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

This solution display only and always 2 ion-select with value : "**test-1","test-2", "test-3"**. It always get the last elements from childrenTags.
Any idea why ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : I'm using Ionic AlertController to generate an alert window with my checkbox inside like it says in the [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#create)

Answer (score 0):

Every time your parent component pass the same index(k) to the `tags-list-component`. In your case it is last index. The reason is first `*ngFor` loop on `parentTags` finished its execution before executing the second `*ngFor` on `childrenTags`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand, but it's strange. I did a test with a simple html <select> instead of the <ion-select> element and it work's ...